# Что такое ошибка разбора html?

Tags: html, css

Validator W3C
Ошибка разбора

```
<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css"> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> <title>Flat</title> </head> <body> <div class="header"> <div class="logo"> <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""> <div class="M_logo">M</div> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

Вот код , попонятней написан:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Flat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
            <div class="M_logo">M</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}


div.header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1680px;
    height: 100px;
}


div.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 164px;
}


div.M-logo {
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

Не применяет стили к div.M-logo, наверное, из-за этой ошибки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в css `M-logo` написан через тире, в html `M_logo` через нижнее подчеркивание. названия должны совпадать

Comment: наоборот, в html через подчёркивание

Comment: Благодарю, Станислав, что-то я проглядел.